# Font Awesome CSS Pseudo-elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

I am using Font Awesome SVG with JavaScript a few times on a project. Now I am trying to create a button so when it is hovered over an arrow icon appears to the right of the text pointing to the right. When the button is hovered over there is just a blank square where the icon should be and the icon is appearing on the left with the text.

Using

```
display:none
```

got rid of the blank icon on the right of the button text.

How do I make the icon appear in the blank square?

This is the code

```js
window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
        searchPseudoElements: true
}
```

```css
.fa-arrow-right:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid';
    content: "\f061";
    font-weight: 900;

}


 .btn-4 {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-4:active {
    border-color: #17954c;
    color: #17954c;
}

.btn-4:hover {
    background: #24b662;
}

.btn-4:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 125%;
    line-height: 3.5;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn-4:active:before {
    color: #17954c;
}

/* Button 4a */
.btn-4a:before {
    left: 130%;
    top: 0;
}

.btn-4a:hover:before {
    left: 80%;
}

/* Button 4b */
.btn-4b:before {
    left: -50%;
    top: 0;
}

.btn-4b:hover:before {
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container mw-100 mx-auto margin-top-70 purple-background">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-8" id="forum">
            <h2 class="text-center margin-top-40">Join the Book Club</h2>
            <p class="feature-text">What are you reading? Share the book love over on the forum</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
          <div class="margin-top-60">
            <button class="btn btn-4 btn-4a fa-arrow-right">Join Us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have taken screenshots to illustrate the problem [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kT7b.png) and [buttons on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbtMx.png)

Comment: Don't you need to load the woff files in your stylesheet?

Comment: A blank square indicates a font is missing, or the element has the wrong font.

Comment: it seems to working fine, what is the issue exactly ?

Comment: Well, since a down voter is down voting all the answers would he/she care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

To use font-awesome you have to define the font-family and in the content introduce awesome font cheatsheet.

Font-family:

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

Content:

```
content: '/f2bb' // exemple
```

Cheatsheet - https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

```css
h1 {
  margin: 25px auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #CD5C5C;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  content: "\f0fc";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Font Awesome With Pseudo-Elements</title>
<!--  Font Awesome 4.6.3 CDN  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Font Awesome with Pseudo-Elements</h1>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Along with the class `fa-arrow-right` also add the class `fa`.

Make sure you remove the extra rules that you've applied.

```
.fa-arrow-right:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid';
    content: "\f061";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

The `fa` class will do all this for you.

Hope that helps.